# How to Get comboBox value from a datagridview cell

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to get value  of a `ComboBox` cell in the `DataGridView` to put it in a Update method for the record. Values for this `ComboBox` are displayed with `DisplayMember` and are stored in the database as `ID`.

This is a `ComboBox` in my `DataGridView` in my form load method with the `ComboBox` cell at Index 15

```
.............
        dgv_Cust.Columns[14].Name="Web";
        dgv_Cust.Columns[14].DataPropertyName = "Web";
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cbcol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        cbcol.Name = "AccStatus";

        cbcol.DataPropertyName = "cbcol"; // DataTable column name
        cbcol.Items.Add(new ComboRecord(0, ""));
        cbcol.Items.Add(new ComboRecord(1, "Active"));
        cbcol.Items.Add(new ComboRecord(2, "NotActive"));
        cbcol.Items.Add(new ComboRecord(3, "Other"));
        cbcol.DisplayMember = "Status";
        cbcol.ValueMember = "IDx";
        cbcol.DisplayIndex = 15;
        dgv_Cust.Columns.Add(cbcol);

        dgv_Cust.Columns[15].Name = "AccStatus";
        dgv_Cust.Columns[15].DataPropertyName = "AccStatus";

        dgv_Cust.ColumnCount = 17;


        dgv_Cust.Columns[16].Name="Location";
        dgv_Cust.Columns[16].DataPropertyName = "Location";

        dgv_Cust.DataSource = DBConn.getCustInfo1();
    }
```

I am getting values from this `DataGridView` to pass it to the Update method like this.....

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   //UpdateCustomer
{

      //Here I want to get valueMember(IDx) for cell[15], from the comboBox          

        string PostalCode = this.dgv_Cust.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        string Name = this.dgv_Cust.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        string BusinessName = this.dgv_Cust.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        string AltName = this.dgv_Cust.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        string Adrs1 = this.dgv_Cust.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
        string Adrs2 = this.dgv_Cust.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
        string City = this.dgv_Cust.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
        string Province = this.dgv_Cust.CurrentRow.Cells[9].Value.ToString();
        string Phone1 = this.dgv_Cust.CurrentRow.Cells[10].Value.ToString();
        string Phone2 = this.dgv_Cust.CurrentRow.Cells[11].Value.ToString();
        string Email1 = this.dgv_Cust.CurrentRow.Cells[12].Value.ToString();
        string Email2 = this.dgv_Cust.CurrentRow.Cells[13].Value.ToString();
        string Web = this.dgv_Cust.CurrentRow.Cells[14].Value.ToString();
        string Location = this.dgv_Cust.CurrentRow.Cells[16].Value.ToString();


        try
        {


            DBConn.updateCustInfo1(AccStatus, PostalCode, Name, BusinessName, AltName, Adrs1, Adrs2, City, Province, Phone1, Phone2, Email1, Email2, Web, Location);
        }
        catch (Exception es)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(es.Message);

        }
```

How do I get `ValueMember(IDx)` from the `DisplayMember`("", "Active", "NotActive", "Other") of the `ComboBox` in the `DGV` as `ComboBox` value is stored as '`IDx`' in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the ID is an int:

```
ComboRecord cr =((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)this.dgv_Cust.CurrentRow.Cells[15]).ValueMember;
int id = cr.xxx ; // replace xxx by the Id property/variable of the ComboRecord
```

If it doesn't work, check with the debugger the types of following items:

```
this.dgv_Cust.CurrentRow.Cells[15].Value
((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)this.dgv_Cust.CurrentRow.Cells[15]).ValueMember
```

Comment: I tried as above but got 'InvalidCastException', specified cast is not valid

Comment: Tried. error -  DataGridViewCell does not contain definition for ValueMember.

Comment: Still no go.. now it gives me error - cannot convert type 'string' to 'int'.                                         this is getting ridiculous... lol

Comment: Graffitto, thank you very much for giving your time to help me. I just gave up for now and see if I can think of other alternative. Never thought it would be so frustrating to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I have similar project for ASP.NET and I use FindControl to find combobox ID

Guess you are using Form, I'd try like that:

```
 ComboBox cbo = this.Controls.Find("combotBox1", true).FirstOrDefault() as ComboBox;
```

[Control.ControlCollection.Find Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)